# isotope-layout with reactjs causes Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'EventEmitter' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, jquery-isotope

I have a **ReactJS** component which renders sub components and I would like to use isotope to display the subcomponents. I use `browserify` and `reactify` to package things up.

In my component.jsx file, this is the only thing that causes the problem:

```
var Isotope = require('isotope-layout');
```

Which js throws the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'EventEmitter' of undefined
```

Particularly caused from this line `var originalGlobalValue = exports.EventEmitter;`

Otherwise, the component works fine without isotope.

I have raised an [issue](https://github.com/metafizzy/isotope/issues/976) on github but I thought it might get more attention here.

And I discovered latter the 'undefined' in the packaged eventemitter code

```
    } else if (typeof module === 'object' && module.exports) {
        module.exports = EventEmitter;
    } else {
        exports.EventEmitter = EventEmitter;
    }
}).call(undefined);
```

After manually changing it to `this` and started to work

```
}).call(this);
```

This is the section in gulp:

```
<pre lang="javascript"><code>
gulp.task('libjs', function() {
    browserify({
        require: libjs,
    }).transform(babelify, {global:true}).transform(reactify, {global:true}).bundle().pipe(source('lib.js')).pipe(gulp.dest(paths.js_built));
})
```

**UPDATE:**

It seems `babelify` is causing this problem. If I don't include `babelify`, it didn't create `}).call(undefined);` in the packaged code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried depending explicitly on `"wolfy87-eventemitter": "4.2.0"`?

Comment: No, I haven't tried, basically I left it off where it was and not to implement isotope in babelify.

Comment: @JamesLin I wasn't using isotope but I had another library (React Masonry) depending on this and what happened is that between 4.2.0 and the latest version code was introduced that causes this error in the browser. If this is not a direct dependency in your code but a dependency of another dependency then just depend on the 4.2.0 (pre-bug) version and you should be good to go. An alternative is to use npm-shrinkwrap to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that `babelify` is causing the issue. However, as explained by [Levi Botelho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1068266/levi-botelho) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34256896/3340229), and in [this issue](https://github.com/metafizzy/isotope/issues/976#issuecomment-164301854), requiring

`"wolfy87-eventemitter": "4.2.0"`

explicitly, solved the issue for us.

Comment: Thank you for confirming this works, I basically don't have the code at that stage anymore but nice to know.